# Optimizing Django View to Handle Large Data Sets Efficiently

Tags: django, query-optimization, django-orm

I'm seeking advice on optimizing a `Django` view to enhance its performance, particularly when dealing with a large number of clients in the database. Here's the scenario:

I have a Django view called `tClients` that retrieves client data and renders it on a webpage. The view performs filtering based on a query parameter called `status`. If `status` is provided and falls within certain values, the view filters clients accordingly.

Here's the current implementation of the view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login')
def tClients(request):
   
    filter_status = request.GET.get('status', None)

    if filter_status is not None and filter_status in ['-1', '0', '1']:
        clients = Client.objects.select_related()
        # values('id','nni','nom','date','telephone','address','observation')


        clients = [client for client in clients if client.is_debt == int(filter_status)]
    else:
        clients = Client.objects.values('id','nni','nom','date','telephone','address','observation')

    context = {
        
        'tClients': clients,
    }

    return render(request, 'clients/list_clients.html', context)
```

The `Client` model is defined as follows:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    nni = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name=_('nni'), unique=True)
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_('nom'))
    date = models.DateField(verbose_name=_("date  d'inscription"))
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='client/qrcodes', blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Image"))
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, verbose_name=_("Telephone"))
    address = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=255, verbose_name=_("Address"))
    observation = models.TextField(null=True, verbose_name=_("Observation"))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def is_debt(self):
        current_date = timezone.localdate()
        debts = self.client_detter.all()
        if debts.exists():
            for debt in debts:
                duration = current_date - debt.date_dette
                duration_in_days = duration.days
                if duration_in_days >= debt.dette_duration and debt.amount != debt.dette_montant_payee:
                    return -1
                elif duration_in_days < debt.dette_duration and debt.amount != debt.dette_montant_payee:
                    return 0
            return 1
        else:
            return 1
```

Initially, I attempted to enhance query performance by utilizing the `values` method to select only the required fields. However, I encountered a challenge when attempting to filter the results based on the `status` parameter.

Since values returns a dictionary, I couldn't directly access the `is_debt` property, which is defined as a `@property` within the `Client` model.

Additionally, I tried annotating the queryset with the `is_debt` property, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired results.

Could anyone provide guidance on how to optimize this query.
Thank you .

**update**
I try annotate with Case/When but didnot work;

```
clients = Client.objects.annotate(
                is_debt=Case(
                    When(client_detter__isnull=False, then=Case(
                    When(
                        ~Q(client_detter__amount=F('client_detter__dette_montant_payee')) &
                        Q(client_detter__date_dette__lte=current_date - F('client_detter__dette_duration')),
                        then=-1
                    ),
                    When(
                        ~Q(client_detter__amount=F('client_detter__dette_montant_payee')) &
                        Q(client_detter__date_dette__gt=current_date - F('client_detter__dette_duration')),
                        then=0
                    ),
                    default=1
                    )),
                    default=1
                )
        ).filter(is_debt=int(filter_status))
```

Comment: What are `NewClient()` and `ClientUpdateForm()`? Share a [example].

Comment: just django forms !

Comment: Have you tried `Case` and `When` in combination with `annotate` which are specific database functions to build conditional sql statements that run directly in the database for Django? When I read your code the logic in `is_debt` are case conditions for annotate.

Comment: Also why use a list comprehension when you can annotate and then call filter on the annotated queryset field?

Comment: @K.John I use `annotate` but didnot work, maybe the conditions in `is_debt` cannot applied in `Case` and `When` , if you can the `annotate` query , please suggest me

Comment: Can you provide the code you personally wrote for Case/When? I wrote a solution but I'm just not too sure of your fields that's why I haven't posted it yet

Comment: Text very long cannot comment it, but not working (posted in Update)